# When using Behave, is it possible to pass a variable into the 'before_all' function in the environment.py file?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, python-behave

I'm using Behave and I have multiple proxies to use for different testing requirements. I've got all the proxy information in my environment.py file, but I'd like to be able to do something like run `behave .\features\automated_test.feature --tags=proxy1` and then in the environment.py file, `proxy1` is passed into the `before_all` function, like `before_all(proxy)`.

That way I can use this line `chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)` and the chosen proxy is passed into it.

environment.py

```html
first_bypassList = [
        "github.com",
        "stackoverflow.com"
]
first_bypassList = ';'.join(first_bypassList)

second_bypassList = [
        "microsoft.com",
        "google.com"
]
second_bypassList = ';'.join(second_bypassList)

if prox == 'first':
        bypassList = first_bypassList
        prox_server = 'firstproxy:3128'
elif prox == 'second':
        bypassList = second_bypassList
        prox_server = 'secondproxy:3128'


def before_all(context):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % prox_server)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=%s" % bypassList)
    context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options)
    context.driver.maximize_window()


def after_all(context):
    context.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part can be done easily if you define your `before_` methods in a separate file, and then import those directly into your `environment.py` file.

Here's an actual selenium behave framework that does that: (SeleniumBase)

https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples/behave_bdd

The `before_` methods were defined at the bottom of https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/behave/behave_sb.py

The `environment.py` file that imports those is here:

https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/features/environment.py

It uses additional command-line options to extend `behave`. Here's a sample run command to run tests via proxy:

```
behave -D proxy=SERVER:PORT
```

Here's one for an authenticated proxy:

```
behave -D proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT
```

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require SeleniumBase? I can define my `before_` methods in a separate file, but I don't have any control when it comes to calling them.

Comment: You can set command-line options that take effect in the file that gets imported by `environment.py`. For example, `-D` can be used to pass custom options.

Comment: I've updated my original question with my environment.py.

So if I use something like `behave .\features\automated_test.feature -D proxy=SERVER:PORT`, how do I access proxy in the `environment.py` so I can run through my if statement. All I really need to do is pass a value into the `prox` variable when I run a test and let my if statement handle it from there. Is that possible?

Comment: It'll be stored in `context`. Use `context.config.userdata` to access the `-D` custom args.

Comment: That worked. Thanks Michael!